# How do I resolve this issue of preventing push to origin wrt. GitHub?

Tags: git, github

When I try to push my application to [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) using [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29), I get the following:

```
$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Medicine - SWEng/.ssh/id_rsa':
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Output of running `git remote -v`:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:young-rain-273.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:young-rain-273.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:SWEngineer7sample_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:SWEngineer7sample_app.git (push)
sample  git@github.com:SWEngineer/sample_app.git (fetch)
sample  git@github.com:SWEngineer/sample_app.git (push)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you do a `git remote -v` and paste the output here?

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the configured URL. What does "git remote show origin" show for fetch and push url?

Comment: it look like you have not properly set up yours RSA keys; check the githut setup docs;

Answer (score 6):

The error message is clear (and correct):

> ERROR: Repository not found.

The problem is that `origin` is set to `git@github.com:SWEngineer7sample_app.git` which is surely wrong. Obviously, you didn't press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>7</kbd>, but only <kbd>7</kbd> when entering the repo path, therefore there's a **7** where there should be a **/**. Simply a typo.

`origin` should be defined same as `sample` (`git@github.com:SWEngineer/sample_app.git`), then GitHub will also find a repo.

To resolve this,

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:SWEngineer/sample_app.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also get "ERROR: Repository not found" if you are trying to push to a repo for which you do not have push access.  It would be nice if the error were more clear, but if (for example) you are pushing to someone else's repo, check with the owner to make sure you have push access.

According to [Help.GitHub - Remotes](http://help.github.com/remotes/):

> First you need a repo on GitHub you can push to. Either create a new repo, gain collaborator permissions on someone else’s repo, or fork someone else’s repo. You can only push to an ssh URL like git@github.com:user/repo.git or an https URL such like https://user@github.com/user/repo.git. If you cloned another repo with a read-only URL you can add a second remote for your URL or remove or rename the existing remote.

Answer (score -1):

You have a public key issue. Use a key with no password, and simply press enter when prompted for one when making it.

Use ssh to the GitHub repository with the `-vvvv` parameter to see which SSH key is being offered.

Comment: If it was a public key issue, the error might instead say "Permission denied (publickey)."