# 12:44:45 PM Push failed: fatal: repository not found but it exists

Tags: android, git, github, android-studio

I am using Github to sync my Android Studio Project.

I have been able to commit and push successfully for over a month.

After adding some files, I received this error.

```
12:44:45 PM Push failed: fatal: repository 'https://rrtigga@github.com/rrtigga.GetDisciplined1_0.git/' not found
```

However, the repo exists...

Here is a snippet from my terminal:

```
Rohits-MacBook-Air:GetDisciplined1_0 Spicycurryman$ git remote add origin rrtigga@github.com:rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
Rohits-MacBook-Air:GetDisciplined1_0 Spicycurryman$
```

This is kind of an awkward error... I did some research and was unable to produce a solution.

[GitHub: ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly (different from similar posts apparently)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922028/github-error-repository-not-found-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

EDIT: It really exists:

https://github.com/rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0

What is the problem here and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a remote called `origin` which is configured to point to `https://github.com/rrtigga.GetDisciplined1_0.git/`, which is not the correct URL for your repository. You should be using either `https://github.com/rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0.git` for access over HTTPS, or `git@github.com:rrtigga/GetDisciplined1_0.git` for SSH.

The error "remote origin already exists" means what it says: you're trying to add a remote with the same name as one that already exists. You need to either delete it first with `git remote rm origin`, or use `git remote set-url` to change the URL of the existing remote.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to get to correct rights, but what do if I receive this: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.