# Create Existing Directory as Repository in GIT

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-16.04

I have a directory say **cplusplus_learn** and my username is **apex_user** (say) in **git**. Inside cplusplus_learn, there are some files and directories which I am practising C++ language. I want to make a repository of same name as **cplusplus_learn** and push every thing in [GITHUB](https://github.com) website. Can someone please explain me the complete steps for doing that.
I went through various links but totally confused. Mostly says that there is already repo is made.

[convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311774/how-to-convert-existing-non-empty-directory-into-a-git-working-directory-and-pus)

[github-error-repository-not-found-fatal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922028/github-error-repository-not-found-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly)

**Note:** All things I want to do from **terminal**.

```
$ cd cplusplus_learn
$ git init .
$ git commit -m 'My first commit'
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/apex-user.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
$ git push -u origin master
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/apex-user/' not found
```

Given above is what I tried. I know there is something wrong but I can't figure that out.

Comment: can you post what you tried and what the error messages were ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to login in to your github account 
and create a repository with the name cplusplus_learn

All things I want to do from terminal.
Just as you have already described. From your description, it seems that you have a wrong remote url already set so you need to update or reset it as shown below

```
$ cd cplusplus_learn
$ git init 
$ git commit -m 'My first commit'
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/apex-user/cplusplus_learn.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

Hopefully this should work. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, I want to know whether I have to create a branch on Github website or can be created in local via terminal and update in Github?

Comment: Yes. You can create a branch on Github website. As well as create a branch locally and push or update it in Github.

Answer (score 3):

- Add your SSH Key into Github profile setting.
- Create a repository on Github. For example (RepoName)
- Navigate into your project directory `cplusplus_learn`.
- Initialize the git `git init`.
- `git remote add origin https://github.com/apex-user/RepoName.git`
- `git add -A`
- `git commit -m "Message you would like to put"`
- `git push origin master`

Comment: As I said, I want everything to do from terminal. Even making a repository, and I dont want to make a new repo. I want my cplusplus_learn to make repo. Please read the complete question. Thanks.

Comment: @Ac3 You need to manually create an empty repo first via github website interface. Git and Github is a different application and you can't create new empty repo in github via git.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking whether there is a way to create repo in github via git.
Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for 2023:**
This should be able to help you.

In your local folder through the command line, execute these list of commands:

1. `git init`
2. `git add . && git commit -m "<Your commit name here>"`
3. `git remote add origin <Github repository URL>` (you can get it from your Github, and if you do not have a repository, you can create that with the help of `gh repo create` command or on the Github website).
4. `git remote -v`
5. `git push --set-upstream origin master`

*You're all set!*

Answer (score 0):

You could use the git hub cli https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create